# How to setup self-closing when I save code on VSCode with prettier and ESLint?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier

I use React and VSCode, I wanna setup self-closing when code is saved but I don't know how...

What I wanna do is

```
<Hello></Hello>
```

after I save code

```
<Hello />
```

Where can I setup self closing?

Thank you.

Comment: There are two VScode settings available see if you have set it somewhat like: `"editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"` and `"editor.formatOnSave": true` in your settings, see if it fixes your thing, I have working on mine so just trying to pinpoint which setting does it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to enable the related rule and make sure `VSCode` is integrated to fix lint warnings/errors on saving.

1. Enable [`react/self-closing-comp`](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/self-closing-comp.md) rule:

```
// eslint config file (package.json / eslintrc / settings.json etc.)
{
  ...
  "rules": {
    "react/self-closing-comp": "error"
  }
}
```

2. Within `settings.json` at `VSCode` make sure you got auto-fix enabled (for example with vscode-eslint extension, it may be any other lint extension related):

```
// settings.json @ VSCode
{ 
...
  "eslint.autoFixOnSave": true,
  "eslint.run": "onSave",
}
```

Refer to [eslint-plugin for vscode](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-eslint) for integration.

Note that [`eslint-config-airbnb`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-airbnb) enables it by default (I suggest using any config).

Comment: I needed to add validate in ESLint on VSCode

Answer (score 4):

Add this ti vscode config:

```
vscode settings.json:

"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
  "source.fixAll.eslint": true
},
```

Answer (score 0):

For as far as I know you can achieve something like that with `"javascript.autoClosingTags": false`. However I know that some part of the community really dislikes this feature since it often closes components that you don't want to be closed. I don't know if you are familiar with Typescript? But if you are I recommend using React in combination with type script (create a project by `npx create-react-app . --typescript`. While developing it automatically checks for these cases and gives you a compile error if you have an empty component.

I hope this answers your question